mmenu.js Scroll top when closing
I'm trying to insert the mmenu into my current page.
I got several issues on this with the markup and positioning header etc.
My main Problem is, that when im closing the menu, it always scrolls the page to top.
I didnt find any options / settings for this behavior.
I want the page to stay on the same position as before opening the menu.
const menu = new Mmenu("#mmenu", {
    hooks: {
    "slidingSubmenus": true,
    "iconPanels": true,
    "wrappers": [
        "bootstrap"
    ],
    "navbars": [
        {
            "position": "top",
            "content": [
                "prev",
                "breadcrumbs",
                "close"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "extensions": [
        "position-front",
        "position-left",
        "multiline",
        "pagedim-black",
        "shadow-page"
    ],
}, {
    "language": "de",
     offCanvas: {
         page: {
             selector: "#page"
         },
         classNames: {
             selected: "active"
         },
     }
});

const api = menu.API;
document.querySelector("#mobile-nav-open")
    .addEventListener(
        "click", () => {
            api.open();
        }
    );

document.querySelector(".mm-blocker")
    .addEventListener(
        "click", () => {
            api.close();
        }
    );

document.querySelector(".mm-btn--close")
    .addEventListener(
        "click", () => {
            api.close();
        }
    );


Solved the issue on my own.
Was another script which used event.stopPropagation();
